# Почему не меняется фото вариации внутри товара?

Tags: php, wordpress

такая проблема в теме woodmart, не меняется фото вариативного товара в зависимости от цвета товара, именоо в Single Product. А в ахривах меняется. Может кто знает в чем пробелма?

[Ссылка на Товар](https://delta-park.humanselabs.online/shop/bortiki-h-14-sm/)
[Ссылка на страницу архива, первый товар вариативный](https://delta-park.humanselabs.online/product-category/ograjdeniya-dlya-klumb-i-gryadok/)

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо следуюшее сделать:

Вам необходимо включить опцию ‘Use images from product variations’ в настроиках темы -> Shop -> Attributes swatches

Then, you need to add images for each variation while editing your product in Dashboard -> Products -> edit product.

Comment: А почему на двух языках, не подскажите?

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, ваш ответ на русский язык, нажав [edit]